# Selecting "Is Library" in android library project does not retain checked after closing configure build path dialog in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, zxing

I am trying to check Is library checkbox in properties>android> "Is Library" checkbox  , and  i do apply and OK. after i verified in the properties>android the "Is Library" is not checked. i tried several times but the check box is not checkd. Im using vista.

Comment: Just had this problem, restarting eclipse solved it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

close and open project helps some times .actually its the permission thing on the file system.

Comment: Hi, I tried both restarting eclipse and opening and closing the project. Neither has helped. I'm actually using multiple libraries for my project, so I don't see why setting a project as a library suddenly isn't working...

Comment: Check the read-only permission in windows file system for the project and try to remove it using command line.